# Unable to reference string - Localization w/ Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

Im having an issue with the below code, its not able to reference the string im pointed the code too.

```
var text = chrome.i18n.getMessage('application_text');

if ($('#multi_select option:selected').text() == text) {

    //If text equals "MY TEXT"

} else {

}
```

HTML

```
<select id='multi_select' name='multi_select'>
        <option value='1' id="multi_select_1"></option>
        <option value='2' id="multi_select_2"></option>
        <option value='3' id="multi_select_3"></option>
</select>
```

Message

```
"application_text": {
"message": "MY TEXT",
"description": "just some text"
}
```

Basically the reference to `text` is not working properly. It will work if i hardcode the string `...text() == "MY TEXT")` However when referencing it from my localized string the code doesnt work.

Comment: Where is the code run from (background page, contet script) ?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the if statement to see what is in text when you do the condition?

Comment: Also: in what directory is the messages text and how is the file named ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem The code is running in my Popup.js not the background.js, As for the message.json its stored in _locales/en/messages.json

Comment: @JaisonBrooks: Did you any luck solving this ? If you feel my answer points to the right direction, consider marking it as accepted, so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to recognise it as useful (without having to read through comments etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a demo extension based on your code and it works just fine. (If you post more code, i.e. whole file content, someone might be able to spot a missing detail.)

Anyway, below is the code for my demo extension (based on your code) that does what you want.
You can check it out or compare it with your own to see where the two differ.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",
    "default_locale": "en",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test Extension",
        "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
    }
}
```

**messages.json:**

```
{
    "application_text": {
        "message": "MY TEXT",
        "description": "just some text"
    }
}
```

**popup.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="multi_select" name="multi_select">
                <option value="1" id="multi_select_1">MY TEXT</option>
                <option value="2" id="multi_select_2">YOUR TEXT</option>
                <option value="3" id="multi_select_3">OTHER TEXT</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var text = chrome.i18n.getMessage('application_text');
    $('#multi_select').on("change", function() {
        if ($('#multi_select option:selected').text() == text) {
            console.log("True");
        } else {
            console.log("False");
        }
    });
});
```